# How to use Activity Trace with Swift under iOS or OS X

Tags: ios, macos, swift

I am trying to figure out how to use Activity Tracing with Swift under iOS and OS X.  Has anyone managed to do this and if so can you provide details of what the Swift API is and where the documentation would be found.

Thanks

Comment: [This objc.io article](http://www.objc.io/issue-19/activity-tracing.html) suggests it's not there in Swift yet, but suggests using Objective-C wrapper and call that from your Swift.

Comment: And with Objective-C wrapper Activity Tracking become completely useless in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following link.
https://www.objc.io/issues/19-debugging/activity-tracing/

It is mentioned that "If you want to use it now within a Swift project, you would have to create an Objective-C wrapper around it and make this API accessible in Swift using the bridging header."

Comment: Hello naz, its same as like using a objective c class in swift using bridging header. Please refer the link:  http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/ios8-how-to-use-objective-c-classes-in-swift/

Comment: os_activity_initiate("activity name", OS_ACTIVITY_FLAG_DEFAULT, ^{
    // do some work...
}); How can you make the name dynamic in Swift?

Comment: It expects a constant. Let me know if you have a suggestion. Does it mean I have to create a copy one for each activity in ObjC and refer to in from Swift? Perhaps I'm just looking for a DRY-er solution